# Windows authentication in ASP.NET 3.5 and MVC4

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

In my company we use a ASP.NET 3.5 portal and after I get authenticated I can open any website inside the portal (and they all written in ASP.NET 3.5).

Right now I want to build a web application in MVC4 (.NET Framework 4.5) and I want to "pass" the authentication from the portal to the new site so when a certain Controller with [Authorized] attribute will authorized the user automatically.

Comment: Can you ask an actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a Single Sign on solution where your users authenticate once and get access to various resources on different web apps.

This is a broad topic, do some research on your own and come back with specific questions on specific protocols/frameworks/implementations.